# What am I, solve this riddle

Tags: riddle

I am first on earth, second in heaven. I appear twice in a week, never in a month, but once in a year.

What am I ?

Answer (score 4):

You are

> The letter "E"

Explanation follows

> I am first on 'e'arth
> second in h'e'aven. 
> I appear twice in a w'ee'k
> never in a month
> but once in a y'e'ar.

Comment: That was answered in a jiffy :)